# Put elements in the popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-6, bootstrap-5, turbolinks

I try to use bootstrap 5 popover, which works very well

```js
// application.js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  // Enable all popovers
  var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
  var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
  })
  // Enable all tooltips
  var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
  var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
  })
});
```

```
    <button type="button"
            id="filterWorkspace"
            class="btn btn-warning"
            data-bs-container="body"
            data-bs-toggle="popover"
            data-bs-placement="bottom"
            data-bs-content="blabla"
    >
      <%= show_svg('filter.svg') %>
    </button>
```

but I would like to add much more content

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#filterWorkspace").popover({
            placement: 'bottom',
            html: 'true',
            title : '<span class="text-info"><strong>title</strong></span>'+
                '<button type="button" id="close" class="close" ...></button>',
            content : 'test'
        });
    });
</script>
```

`jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).popover is not a function TypeError: $(...).popover is not a function`

I don't really understand because I have other parts of the code that use jquery even if the problem here is that it does not recognize popover

EDIT

```js
// application.js
global.$ = require("jquery")
```

```js
// environment.js
environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  bootstrap: 'bootstrap',
  Popper: ['@popperjs/core', 'default']
}))
```

Comment: Either you call popover before you add the library or you included jQuery two times on the page.

Comment: I solved the order problem, it didn't come from there.
and for the jquery I don't know

Comment: according to the network there is no file addition